Solovay-Strassen Test
Proposition: Suppose $n \geq 3$ is odd and $\forall a$ with $\gcd(a,n) = 1$, we have $a^{(n - 1) / 2} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod n$.
If any of the following statements are true:
I) $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$;
II) $\exists b$ with $\gcd(b,n) = 1$ such that $b^{(n - 1) / 2} \equiv - 1 \pmod n$.
Then $n$ is prime.
Guys, I know that $n$ is a prime, but I don't even know how to start writing it. I need to demonstrate it mathematically. Please help me.

Hello and welcome to mth.stackexchange. What exactly is your question? Are your trying to prove this proposition? Are you trying to apply it?

Olá! Obrigada pela recepção. Estou tentando provar a proposição, mas não sei nem como começar.
